# How to get the full path of a file in python including the subdirectory?

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system

I tried every method, but it simply doesn't work. I have a file that is within a subdirectory and that subdirectory lies within a directory. Calling something like

```
os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

only yields

```
directory\\file
```

but I need

```
directory\\subdirectory\\file
```

There should be an easy way to do this, right? I have no idea why abspath doesn't recognize the subdirectory.

Comment: Can you paste the code which is used to assign the file object to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

my_path = Path("my_file.txt")
full_path = Path.resolve()
```

Then you can convert full_path to a string if you need it as such.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: Which method though? I can't find anything helpful there.